# Chamisha Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/US-Israel/HRes185.html

here you can see the text of house resolution 185 which recognizes Jewish refugees from Arab lands.

Answer (score 2):

Tanach compares the wicked King Menashe of Judah to the equally wicked King Achav of Israel (II Kings 21:3) - indeed, the Gemara (Sanhedrin 102b-103a) derives a couple of facts about him from this comparison.

Their reigns were separated by 185 years: Achav was killed in battle in 3043, Menashe's reign began in 3228.

Answer (score 1):

From Pesach up to and including Shemini Atzeres is exactly 185 days long.